# zf2 virtual host loading localhost/xampp

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, xampp, vhosts

I'm trying to get zf2 running on my xampp.
I have this vhosts.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial"    
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this host file

```
127.0.0.1   zf2-tutorial.localhost
```

Now, when I run `zf2-tutorial.localhost`, the browser goes to `zf2-tutorial.localhost/xampp` and shows xampp page.

When I run `localhost` it goes to `localhost/xampp` too.

Please help.

Comment: I got working the vhost with the configuration mentioned in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031044/virtual-host-redirecting-to-the-xampp-folder-but-only-when-accessing-by-a-remot, but not working when access it from a remote machine. I have not solved the problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/public

If that works you could change the following entries in your vhosts file

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public"    

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public">
```